# Better positioning of ddots in matrix

Tags: matrices

How can i improve the representation of this matrix?
The problem is that the `\ddots` in the middle are not properly aligned. 
It should say that `a` and `b` gets succesively gets moved one column further to the right.

Maybe there is `\ddots` with a smaller slope?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
%opening

\begin{document}

\[
\left(\begin{array}[c]{c|cccccc}
            &   & c      & \ldots & c      & c \\ \hline
            & 0 &        &        &        & 0 \\
     d      & a & b      &        &        &   \\
     \vdots &   & \ddots &        & \ddots &   \\
     d      &   &        &        & a      & b
\end{array}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Move the first `\ddots` to the next cell and it looks just fine. If you align all the `&` it is easier to see where everything goes. You might even want to remove the last `\ddots`

Comment: there an automatic way to do this?

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: the alignment of the &

Comment: My editor (emacs) has a build in feature for it. There might be other editors who can do the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a different suggestion: simplify the matrix from a 5x5 to a 4x4 structure, to emphasize that the lower-right block of the full-matrix is (to my understanding) a triangular matrix, with zeroes above the diagonal.

[image]

There seems to be an implicit assumption that your readers "know" what's in the top-left block and in the first positions of row- and column vectors. Is this assumption justified?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(\begin{array}{c|cccc}
       &   & c      & \ldots & c \\ 
\hline
       & 0 &        &        & 0\\
d      & a & b      &        &  \\
\vdots &   & \ddots & \ddots &  \\
d      &   &        & a      & b
\end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pNiceArray}{c|ccccc}
        &   & c      & \Ldots & c & c \\ \cmidrule(rl){1-6}
        & 0 &        &        &   & 0 \\
 d      & a & b      &        &   &   \\
 \Vdots &   & \Ddots & \Ddots \\
\\
 d      &   &        &        & a & b
\end{pNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I think the top horizontal rule should be shortened on both sides a bit to not be connected with the parantheses.

Comment: @Diaa: You are right. I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can rotate the dots a bit and possibly put them higher using the `\rotatebox` and `\raisebox` commands from the `graphicx` package. Note that this requires the dots to be put in math mode explicitly, even if they are already in a math environment. With `\smash` you can prevent the rotated/raised boxes from increasing the height of the array row.

However, I agree with the comments that a single `\ddots` is probably better.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(\begin{array}[c]{c|cccccc}
        &   & c                                & \ldots                                           & c & c \\ \hline
        & 0 &                                  &                                                  &   & 0 \\
 d      & a & b                                &                                                  &   &   \\
 \vdots &   & \smash{\rotatebox{20}{$\ddots$}} & \smash{\raisebox{3pt}{\rotatebox{20}{$\ddots$}}} &   &   \\
 d      &   &                                  &                                                  & a & b
\end{array}\right)
\]

\[
\left(\begin{array}[c]{c|cccccc}
       &   & c & \ldots & c & c \\ \hline
       & 0 &   &        &   & 0 \\
d      & a & b &        &   &   \\
\vdots &   &   & \ddots &   &   \\
d      &   &   &        & a & b
\end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]